# How to "config" in python?

Tags: python, config

What is the best way to write configuration files and access them in python. I have done some ground work and found [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) coupled with `*.ini` files. Is this the best way to do the same or is there any other way?

[Edit] I am working on a project to detect abnormalities in the system and notify me. So when the app starts I reads some values like to_email_address, from_email_address, from_email_password etc, which are independent of the machine I run the code. For example, the machine that hosts my website will send notifications to my personal id. The machines which run certain service may notify my developers. So I want to separate them from code base.

Comment: Can you  be more specific about your use case?  As is, this question is a little too broad to generate a useful answer.

Comment: Why not just write a `settings.py` file?  Is there a reason you need `*.ini` files?

Comment: While creating a code file to function as a config works, it's not always a great idea.  When the config becomes part of your codebase, it makes managing deployments to dissimilar environments harder, and creates a hard-to-resist temptation to perform logic in your configs, which breaks separation of duties and makes projects harder to debug.

Answer (score 3):

This is an opinion-based question so I'll share my opinions.

- `.ini` files are a good choice for simple configuration files. Such files are fairly
  human-readable and easy to edit manually. Also, Windows users are likely to be familiar with them already.
- `JSON` has a fairly lightweight syntax and can handle nested
  configuration settings (options inside options) using nested
  dictionaries or lists. It is also typed (although the types supported
  are basic) so you can distinguish between numbers, strings, and
  missing data (received in Python as `None`) easily. It interoperates
  with JavaScript very easily so might be extra appropriate if some
  configuration will be shared with a Web app.
- `XML` is more verbose than JSON, but much more flexible, and you can
  (in theory) define schemas that assure you receive valid data from
  the file or it won't parse at all. Unfortunately this can make them
  rather fragile if users are editing them by hand and aren't aware of
  the restrictions. Everybody in Java-land uses XML, so if you are
  looking to interoperate with Java in some way, that might tip the
  scales in its favor.
- I don't know much about `YAML`, but it's another choice. A quick look at it: seems more human-readable and straightforward to edit than JSON or XML, but supports some hierarchy, placing it between `.ini` files and JSON in terms of capability.

Python has libraries for reading and writing all these formats. They are all text-based, which is nice if you expect your users to want to put your config files under version control, as they might if it is a server or system administration tool. Also, many text editors will have handy highlighting features for such files.

You also have the option of storing data using the `pickle` module. The advantage of this is that it is a native Python format and you can therefore pickle most types of objects (even your own types) and get back exactly what you wrote out. However, if users will need to edit your config file by hand, it is not at all user-friendly, and it doesn't play well with other languages, either. It might be suitable if you provide a GUI for editing settings and there aren't too many of them.

Answer (score 2):

As I am unable to upvote because of no reputation I will just provide my own answer here.
The ConfigParser is very nice, as it will silently ignore reading an inifile that is not there.
So to provide default values from code as lzkata suggests You could do something like:

```
import ConfigParser
conf = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

conf.add_section("base")
conf.set("base","path","/")

conf.read("config.ini")
conf.write(open("config.ini","w"))

print conf.get("base","path")
```

After running the program the first time, the 'config.ini' file is there and if you change the value in the file it will be reflected when You rerun the program.

Answer (score 0):

ConfigParser works well for simple use cases. If you have complex configuration where you don't know the types of all the configuration data passed to your application, you might want to look into something more robust like [YAML](http://pyyaml.org/).